# Convergence of conditional distributions given convergence of conditioning set

Tags: probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Suppose that $X_n \stackrel{p}\rightarrow X$. Is it true that $\mathbb{P}(Y|X_n)$ converges in distribution to $\mathbb{P}(Y|X)$? I.e. $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y |X_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(Y\leq y |X)$

This is probably not true, but I am interested in maybe some weak conditions where it is true. For example, if we have $(x,y) \mapsto \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y|X=x)$ is a continuous function of $x$ for every $y$...

The best I can get: if we have $(x,y) \mapsto \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y|X=x)$ is a continuous function of $x$ for every $y$, then $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y |X_n) \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{P}(Y\leq y |X)$ by the continuous mapping theorem, but I am not sure convergence in probability of distributions makes sense...

Comment: I guess you can do a lot of things to "mess" this up. As a family of examples, consider the case when $\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X\}$ is an independent set and have $Y$ depend on $X$. E.g., take $X_n$ to be the proportion of heads in $n$ unbiased and independent coin flips. Then $X$ is some normal distribution by the CLT. Then, take $Y = X$ (though as you point out, this would be precluded by your continuity assumption).

Comment: I think I realized what is wrong. I should not be viewing $X_n$ and $X$ as random variables when dealing with the conditional distributions. So $X_n \rightarrow X$ implies $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y|X_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y | X)$ (ordinary convergence)

Comment: Maybe you are confused as to what $\mathbb{P}(X|Y)$ means. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution. If you are not familiar with measure theory, it might be helpful to restrict your attention to a particular case (e.g., continuous densities).